# My Laravel required_without_all validation is not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I am working on a project, where I have three fields 1. csv file upload(email) 2. comma separated string(emails) 3. dynamic input field(email), any one of these fields is required.

My approach for validation:

```
'comma_separated' => ['nullable','required_without_all:email.*,file'],
'file' => ['nullable','required_without_all:email.*,comma_separated', 'mimes:csv'],
'email.*' => ['nullable','required_without_all:comma_separated,file','email'],
```

If I enter email in dynamic field, its asking me for file and comma_separated fields.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thank You.

Comment: did you try putting `email` and not `email.*` in the required_without_all: of the other fields ?

Comment: yes, i tried but without success

Comment: *If I enter the email in dynamic field*. Where is the dynamic field ?

Comment: email.* is dynamic field

Comment: email.* is creating issue, I have tested by disabling this field & everything is working perfectly.